# How can I write this in Python?

Tags: php, python

```
$class->categories[$cat->category_parent_id][]=$cat;
```

I have developed a script where I want to write this php code in python.

How can I create a this `categories` array in python?

So far I have done this:

```
categories_c.insert(row["category_parent_id"], row)
```

But I am not sure if this is the correct implementation.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code translation service

Comment: one way could be to learn python. another is to hire an intern who knows python.

Answer (score 4):

Let's deconstruct:

```
$class->categories
```

This accesses the `categories` property of the `$class` object. In Python that's:

```
klass.categories  # (class is a reserved keyword, using klass instead)
```

We'll assume that `categories` is a `dict` here, because you want to do this:

```
categories[$cat->category_parent_id]
```

This accesses a particular key of an array, in Python that would be the key of a `dict`:

```
categories[cat.category_parent_id]
```

Now the tricky part:

```
...[] = $cat
```

This pushes `$cat` into the array. In Python that means `append`ing a value to a `list`. PHP will implicitly create new sub-arrays as necessary if they don't exist. **Python doesn't.** This is the only part that needs a bit of additional consideration. What you need to know is whether `categories[cat.category_parent_id]` already exists in your `dict` or whether you want to create it in the process.

If you know it exists, if `categories` is a `dict` of `list`s in which all `cat.category_parent_id` keys are already pre-populated, then it's as simple as this:

```
klass.categories[cat.category_parent_id].append(cat)
```

However, if the keys don't exist, you must ensure they're created and that their value is set to a `list` the first time they're accessed. The most compact notation for that in Python is the `dict.setdefault` method:

```
klass.categories.setdefault(cat.category_parent_id, []).append(cat)
```

If `categories[cat.category_parent_id]` exists, it is returned and you can `append` to it. If it doesn't exist, it is created and initialised to `[]` and then returned.

Comment: What I forgot to mention was that `cat` here is a record obtained by firing a mysql query. Will it matter or not?

Comment: No? Yes? Maybe? That depends on what exactly it is, what you want it to be and whether it poses any problem as is.

Comment: `for child in categories[cat["category_parent_id"]]:` is this the correct implementation for retrieving data from `categories` ?

Comment: I don't know because I do not have enough context to answer this.

Comment: OK, I don't know what your data looks like. As written, I've made a number of assumptions in my answer. You will have to provide a lot more details if you want more detailed help. Post a new question for that.